# How can I improve the visualization of a band structure plot for a dense supercell?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, band-structure, condensed-matter

I computed the band structure of my material's supercell using Quantum ESPRESSO,but the resulting plot appears to be densely populated with bands, like in the picture bellow:

[image]

Could someone provide guidance on how to adjust the visualization to achieve a more typical representation, please?

Comment: Could you please add the data file from where you obtained this plot? I have seen many articles using this type of densely populated band such as in Fig. 2 of [this](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.56.14993). To improve this plot, you can reduce the line width of each band. Also, your lines seem to be pixelated. You can try to smooth it out.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin How can I reduce the line width of each band, please?

Comment: it depends on the code/software you used to plot your data file. Could you also add the plotting script you are using to obtain this plot? That way someone can modify your code to reduce the line width.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin I modified the line width in Xmgrace, the plot was better actually, but not like I want. I found something in the internet about unfolding bandstructure. I'm searching for a non computationally expensive way to do this unfolding just by using my laptop because it's not installed in the HPC i'm using, I think it's not something very known.